# Riemann Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ be a bounded function. Suppose that there exists a sequence of partitions
 
$\{P_k\}$ of $[a,b]$ such that
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}(U(P_k,f)-L(P_k,f)) = 0$$
Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable and that
$$\int_{a}^{b}f=\lim_{k\to\infty}U(P_k,f)=\lim_{k\to\infty}L(P_k,f)$$

Comment: You should show your own thoughts.  In particular, tell us the definition of "Riemann integrable" according to your textbook... Probably some results on Riemann integral are in your textbook, and you should use them to prove this.  But we don't know what they are, since textbooks differ in their order of presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there exists a sequence of partitions $P_n$
satisfying $lim[U(f ,P_n)-L(f, P_n)]$ = 0:
Given ϵ> 0, choose $P_N$ from this sequence so that $ U(f, P_N)-L(f, P_N) <ϵ$.
Then f is integrable.
 Conversely, if f is integrable then  there exists a partition $P_n$ satisfying $U(f, P_n)-L(f, P_n) < 1/n$. It follows that $lim[U(f, P_n)- L(f, P_n)] = 0$;as desired.